# How do I update my Elastic beanstalk application code using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

How do I update my application code on Elastic Beanstalk using the AWS CLI (NOT the Elastic Beanstalk CLI)? We recently decided to enforce MFA for all users on AWS, I was able to configure the AWS CLI (aws) to use MFA using by updating my credentials file with a session token. I am now able to use `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment`. However deploying the application code using the Elastic Beanstalk CLI with `eb deploy` fails with an "access denied" error. When I remove the MFA policy `eb deploy` works. I think the solution is just to use the AWS CLI instead. However I can't figure out what the AWS CLI equivalent to `eb deploy`is.

Comment: [The commands `aws elasticbeanstalk` supports are listed on the documentation site](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html), but none of them is exactly the same as `eb deploy` which does multiple things under the hood.  Looking at the documentation of `eb` it seems like it does support profiles in ~/.aws/config so it would be a pretty unfortunate omission if it didn't support best practices like MFA or SSO.

Answer (score 1):

turns out it takes a few steps to get it done:

```
    aws s3 cp $VER.zip s3://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-<accountId> --profile MFA  
    aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --region us-west-2 --application-name $APP --version-label $VER --source-bundle S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-<accountId>,S3Key=$VER.zip --profile MFA
    aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --region us-west-2 --environment-name $DIR --version-label $VER --profile MFA
```